# Domain of $( \frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}})^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus

Find the Domain of $\left(\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}\right)^{1/2}$ where $\{\}$ denotes the fractional part function.

$\left(\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}\right)$ should be positive,
$\left(\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}\right)\ge0$.
The denominator can't be zero, so $x≠0$. I can't do anything else.

How can I proceed$?$

Comment: To be positive, either top & bottom are both positive, or both negative.

Comment: @runway44 , I'm having problem with determining the values for which denominator is negative and positive.

Comment: [Have a gander at graphs](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dx%2C+y%3D2FractionalPart%5Bx%5D+from+x%3D-3+to+3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\{ x \} $ will always be less than 1. Therefore, $2\{ x \} $  will be less than 2. Thus, $x-2\{ x \} $ will be positive for $x>2$.

We then check 2 itself. Replacing $x$ with 2, it is clear that the function is defined as numerator and denominator are positive.

Next, we can look at the interval $(1, 2)$. On that interval, the $\{ x\} $ is just $x-1$, making the denominator $2-x$, which is always positive on $(1,2)$. Since the numerator is positive here also, the function is defined.

At 1 the function is defined.

Next, check $(0,1)$. The denominator is just $x-2x=-x$. So the denominator is negative, as is the numerator. Thus the function is defined.

Continue like this into negative intervals and see if you can finish a similar argument!

Comment: So, the domain should be $R - \{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 1):

**Condition 1.** $x-2\{x\}\ne 0$.

Since $0\le\{x\}<1$, $0\le 2\{x\}<2$.

- If $x<0$, $x-\underbrace{2\{x\}}_{\ge 0}<0$, so $x-2\{x\}\ne 0$.
- If $x\ge 2$, $x-\underbrace{2\{x\}}_{<2}>0$, so $x-2\{x\}\ne 0$.
- If $x\in[0,1)$: $x=\{x\}\implies x-2\{x\}=-\{x\}=-x\le 0$, equality holds only if $x=0$ (in this case).
- If $x\in[1,2)$: $x=1+\{x\}\implies x-2\{x\}=1-\{x\}>0$.

**Condition 2.** $\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}\ge 0$.

Make a table of signs (where $|$ means *undefined* and $)$ and $[$ mark inclusivity/exclusivity):
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}x&-\infty & & 0 & & 1 & & \infty\\\hline  x-1 & - & - & - & - & 0&+&+\\\hline x-2\{x\} &-&-&0&-)&[+&+&+\\\hline \frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}} & + & + & | &+ & 0 & + & +\end{array}$$

Conclude that $\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}}$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^*$. Note: Assumes that you use the "standard" definition, $\{x\}=x-\max_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} k\le x$